# Failed to update .mdf database because the database is read-only (Windows application)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, windows-vista

I've created a database windows application using in C#. My application is running successfully on Windows XP, but it doesn't properly execute on Vista or Windows 7 systems. My application shows a message similar to

> Failed to update .mdf database because the database is read-only

Can anyone give me a solution to this?

Comment: Where is the database file stored, how is it accessed? Are you using Sql Server user instances? **Show us some code**! =)

Comment: Database file is stored in my application path and i've using ado.net

Comment: **show us some code** - you've obviously got some, as it's not working and it'd certainly help us diagnose the issue! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MDB file is in your application path, then the default permissions would require elevation of rights to be able to write to the files -- I'd recommend moving the data to the ApplicationData shared folder, where end users will have write permissions by default

Comment: Thanks, Here i'm using this code,do you know Identity parameter of FileSystemAccessRule Class
Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
            dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("?", FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
            Directory.SetAccessControl(path, dirSec)

Comment: @Ambarish you really should consider saving the data file in a path that is intended for data, which would make that step unnecessary - you can after all you can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))` to retrieve the location programmatically for per-user settings (or change to use `CommonApplicationData` for per-machine data)

Comment: @Shaw how can i store my database my files to C:\ProgramData

Answer (score 8):

The big thing that changed between Windows XP and Windows Vista/7 is the introduction of UAC which means that users, even if created as administrators, don't routinely have read/write access to "important" locations such as the `%programfiles%` (Usually `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`) directory. This is why your application works on Windows XP and not on Windows Vista.

You need to store your **DATA** in the `%programdata%` directory (which is usually `C:\ProgramData`) if the data is shared between users on the machine or `%appdata%` (which is usually `C:\Users\USERNAME_GOES_HERE\AppData\Roaming`) if it is specific to a given user. You'll now no longer encounter the problem of being unable to write to the file.

The reason for this is that *by storing data in your programs installation directory you were **doing the wrong thing***. Windows didn't stop you from doing this previously, but it was fairly widely documented that `%programfiles%` was not the appropriate place to store data.

Comment: Yes dear @Ambarish It dose work; But why you didn't marked it as answer?

Comment: Hi, I am following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTIF8wNxcWY&list=PLHpWiazdjdBKA8HNGCbtiK7hzlW5h3eF-&index=14 . How can I change the connection string to AppData folder? I have setup project in the same for installing the aplication.

Comment: @S.B. - ask a fresh question, *don't* use comments on someone else's question. You also need to *distil* what's relevant from the video. There is almost no chance that I (or anyone else!) will sit and watch a nine and a half minute long video to get context

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this related to localdb, the file is named:

```
myfolder/mysolution/myproject/App_Data/something.mdf
```

The way I fixed it is to right-click on the top level folder (`myfolder`) and then choose `Properties`, then choose `Edit`, then select `Users`, add to users either the `Modify` permission or both `Modify` and full control (this is a development environment) and then click apply.

So in other words, in my experience, it doesn't matter what folder you put the localdb in, you just need to give Users permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the *Modify* permissions for **IIS_IUSRS** user to ***.mdf** file.

Answer (score -1):

go to the folder Where the program is installed and right click on the database file and Properties -> Security -> Group or Username (Click users one by one and see below for the permissions)

If for the user if not set to full control, then click EDIT -> Select the user and give full control..