# error give message "Failed to update database because database is read only."

Tags: database

When I run window form application in Visual Studio it works, but when make setup of it.
two issues occurs:

1. Either application doesn't runs.
2. Gives message:

> Failed to update database because database is read only.

I am using `.mdf` database file in project. `.mdf` file lie in the project folder.

Please provide full detail to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, which database engine? How is it (the server) being connected to? What are the permissions on the database file(s)? Etc.

Comment: database engine sqlexpress, there is no server it is desktop application .there is no option for permission on mdf file only one option copy to output directory is copy always.

Comment: if you wish then i can send whole project............

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713416/failed-to-update-mdf-database-because-the-database-is-read-only-windows-applic