# Failed to update database "*.mdf" because read only EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, permissions

I have a C# .NET Framework 4.0 desktop application with Entity Framework as DAL.
When a try to save a data into DBContext on anybodies machine but mine, I recieved an exception

```
Failed to update database "*.mdf" read only
```

I keep my DB near .exe file, in folder "DAL/AppData".

How can I allow write access on other machines?
Can I do it programmatically?

I've read that I can place DB into AppRoaming Folder, but this is not my variant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read only database - Entity Framework is not even part of the game.

Comment: Following link for answer works for u:-

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713416/failed-to-update-mdf-database-because-the-database-is-read-only-windows-applic>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I keep my DB near .exe file, in folder "DAL/AppData".

Yes. Can it be you mean that this is in the programs file folder, you know.

THe one that windows specs of the last 10 years say is "read only" for normal users?

OUCH.

THer are folders for storing data. There is a SpecialFolders enumeration to get the valid path of every such folder.

> How can I allow write access on other machines? Can I do it programmatically?

On a SQL Server, this is done by allowing the other computer to access the server, not the data files. I.e. you connect to the SQL Server on the other machine, which is having the database loaded.

> I've read that I can place DB into AppRoaming Folder, but this is not my variant.

First, that would be stupid unless you do actually plan for roaming - SQL shold go into a local folder, never roaming.

Second, "not my variant" is like "Hey, I drive the car against the rules, what can I do not to get speeding tickets". And "following the law is not my variant". Your variant is something WIndows does not care for. Learn how to install your software according to the windows guideline which is VERY clear where changing data should NOT be.

Comment: Okay, I've understand my mistake. Thanks a lot, I will work on that way now.

Comment: I did't know that I'm fighting against the rules, I'm novice in MS SQL