# Cannot update the database (LocalDB)

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, web, web-deployment, localdb

I have written an application in code-first approach (ASP.NET MVC), and now I am trying to deploy my application on a server (Windows Server 2012). When I test it in Visual Studio 2013 for WEB everything goes fine. After the implementation, when I access website for web, i cannot for example add next user because:

> Failed to update database "MyDatabase" because the database is read-only.

I checked the instances in LocalDB folder, and they are really read-only. The change of it in properties menu doesn't work. 
This is stack tree:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to update database "MyDatabase" because the database is read-only.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6553853
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +6556619
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +586
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +742
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +287
>      WebMatrix.Data.Database.Execute(String commandText, Object[] args) +178
>      WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(IDatabase db, Int32 userId, String password) +455
>      WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +238
>      WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistCookie) +73
>      MvcApplication4.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) +132
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +179
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +258
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +124
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +786611
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +786611
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +33
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +787092
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: Is this a SQLExpress db?

Comment: Yes it is SQLExpress db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a SQLExpress DB, take a look at this answer. It looks to be the same issue you are having.

[Failed to update .mdf database because the database is read-only (Windows application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713416/failed-to-update-mdf-database-because-the-database-is-read-only-windows-applic)

**Update**

For the .mdf and .idf files, give write and modify access to NETWORK SERVICE user, ASPNET user, and IIS_IUSRS group.

Comment: I think this is not the case. The database that is accessed is generated in locadDB folder, and I cannot simply move it (or can I?). The problem is that I was ordered to make the implementation of the application that was written by someone else, and I don't know the whole code.

Comment: I updated my answer with another approach, maybe that will get it done.

Comment: I am quiet newbie in this topic, co could you tell me how to do it? I found only the description of Network Service as the account.

Comment: First find the .mdf and .idf files. One at a time, right click on it and select Properties > Security tab. Click the Edit button, then the Add button. Then click Advanced button. There you need to make sure "From this location:" is set to the machine and not a domain. You can click the Locations button and select to top machine to make sure. Once that's done click the Find Now button. Select NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_IUSRS, then click Ok and Ok again. They will now appear in the list and you can select them and check modify and write in the permissions box. Then click Ok and try it.

Comment: And one more thing, when the database is created, it doesn't display in the folder. I think it's crucial

Comment: After you update the permissions restart IIS. Where are the .mdf and .idf files located?

Comment: Again, the same problem. Nothing has changed. The are located in instance in LocalDB folder

Comment: Ok it works, I changed persmission for the whole application and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the permissions of the entire folder where the website was hosted. I added all permissions for `Users` to be broad and it worked. Try this first to be sure and then narrow it down to specific users.

A restart of the IIS was not required.